# getting the list of files inside a folder using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an url that is listing the files inside a folder:

[image]

Using javascript I need to obtain that list of files.

My code:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://webtests02/pruebas/',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

The thing is I am getting nothing as the return of the ajax GET call.

I tried other formats like using $.get but the result is the same so I cloncluded that or as it is not a .html, .aspx I can't get the code and scrape the content or the IIS is blocking these requests so I can't get it using jquery...

The website is mine so I can configure whatever needed in the IIS...

EDIT: I created an asp website that lists the files in the folder:

[image]

But I am still getting an empty response when I make the ajax call:

[image]

EDIT: THREAD CLOSED. It was due to a CORS authorization error.

Comment: You can call ajax to php script its send list of files array.

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: @madalinivascu No console errors..

Comment: @RaghavRangani I have a lot of folders (websites), you mean, creating a php that lists the files and copying the php script in every folder?

Comment: only you send folder path.

Answer (score 0):

Newer implementations of jQuery use the .done() method on the Ajax object to deal with completion and data of the AJAX call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png", 
    beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
        xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
    }
}).done(function( data ) {
    if ( console && console.log ) {
        console.log( "Sample of data:", data.slice( 0, 100 ) );
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

Comment: I tried this solution but I am still getting an empty response when getting http://webtests02/pruebas/

Comment: Check the browser dev console under the "Network" tab. Hit the url and check exactly what data you are getting as response. That might help in handling it appropriately.